# How to trim the space in the contents page?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I hope to remove some vertical space between the top of the content page and the word "Contents" so as to put a bit more lines in the page. I am using the "titletoc" package. Are there any way to customize this spacing by using any command in the titletoc package?

Comment: If your class is based on `article` (It _always_ helps to provide an example document showing the class used) then you can simply go `\vspace*{-1cm}\tableofcontents`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your idea, but this method fails in my case. It just creates one empty page before the content page.

Comment: You have edited the question but still not provided the needed information: tableofcontents just uses one of the standard document class headings (typically chapter or section) section headings don't normally start a new page (so just inserting negative space will work) chapter headings normally have more complicated layout and do start a new page, so the details of how to change the layout depend on the original layout. It is the document class that defines the tableofcontents command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I suppose it is using the chapter headings since I am using "book" as my document class. Therefore it starts a new page. Is there any solution in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please *always* provide a complete document in the question, something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
{\makeatletter
\let\old@makeschapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\def\@makeschapterhead{\vspace*{-1cm}\old@makeschapterhead}
\tableofcontents
}
\chapter{aaa}
\section{bbb}
zzz
\end{document}
```